# Redux form set custom error message based on field's hinttext in Field Validation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-form

I am trying to write a [Field validation](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/fieldLevelValidation/) so that i don't have to write separate validation in every file. While trying to do it, i am able to get value of the field as well as the whole form fields.

I have to set the error message based on the field name, eg.

For field name as Firstname the error message has to be : First name is invalid.

is there a way to implement this with the Field Validation,  or the sync validation is the only way?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "hacky" way to do this. Since in field validation you get field `value` and form `values` as parameters, you could get field name (which would be the key of the form `values` object) by searching for a matching `value` in form `values`. Then you would need to have a file with field name translations where you could get the field name, e.g. `translations[fieldName]`.

However, since the above way requires more setup and sync validation is relatively simple, I would recommend using sync validation.

Comment: Thanks Deividas,but  i used another way, appended the error text to the name of the field, solved my issue.